# why is my audio code crashing

Tags: html, audio, mp3

I hame an mp3 file loaded in javascript like so:

```
var q=new Audio('path/to/file');
var restart=function(){
  q.currentTime=0;
  q.play();
};
q.addEventListener('canplaythrough',function(){
  setInterval(9000,restart);
});
```

The audio file is only about 5 seconds long. The first time `restart` is called there is no problem. However 9 seconds later on the next call the audio restarts and plays through but the browser crashes. Even the console crashes so I can't inspect anything or read any errors. I am using the latest version of chrome. I have tested this code with several files to ensure it is not a corruption issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that setting `cuurentTime` is triggering the `canplaythrough` event. I resolved the issue by removing the event handler after it fires:

```
var q=new Audio('path/to/file');
var restart=function(){
  q.currentTime=0;
  q.play();
};
var ff=function(){
  setInterval(9000,restart);
  q.removeEventListener('canplaythrough',ff);
};
q.addEventListener('canplaythrough',ff);
```